# Trace of a square Matrix

Tags: c#, arrays, properties, matrix

I'd like to create a property that returns the Trace of a square Matrix.
The Trace of a Matrix is the sum of its diagonal elements.
This code doesn't work. I don't know why!

```
public double Trace
        {
            double x;
            get
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.NbrRows(); i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < this.NbrColumns(); j++)
                        if (i == j)
                            return x += this.array2D[i, j];
            }
        }
```

Comment: This looks like homework. But anyway, are you sure that the matrix used is square?

Comment: There's syntax errors and logical errors here that prevent this from being correct.

Comment: Indeed, but I have this error `A get or set accessor expected` in `double x`. Not a test error

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `return` before `x+= this.array2D[i, j];` and just `return x;` after the outer for loop.

Comment: Initialize double x with a value (0 most likely)

Comment: Show us more of your class i.e. where your private fields are declared

Comment: While we're at it you might want to consider somthing. If you check if the matrix is square beforehand, you can just do this with one for loop. ex:

    if (this.NbrRows() == this.NbrColumns())
        for (int i=0; i<this.NbrRows(); i++)
            x += this.array2D[i, i];

Since we know we only want to sum the elements where row = col, we can  reduce algorithmic complexity in this way.

You may have posted more details as I was typing this so I'll stay on the lookout.